# Can I spy object that uses a get method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spy

I have a simple question, what have I done wrong? I have created a spy for SomeClass. here is the code:

```
public class SomeClass {

   protected Car car;

   public SomeClass(Car car) {
      this.car = car;
   }


   public void doSomething() {

      BMW bmw = car.getBMW();
      bmw.setWheels(null);

      if(StringUtils.isEmptyStringOrNull(bmw.getWheels())) {
         throw new Exception e;
      }
   }
}
```

There are more stuff happening in the doSomething method I just shortened it just for the problem I have, I can't change it. here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

   private SomeClass someClassTest;
   private Car carTest;

   @Before 
   public void setUp() {
      carTest = new Car(createVolkswagen(), createBMW());
      someClassTest = new SomeClass(car);
   }

   @Test
   public void doSomethingTest() {
      BMW spy = spy(carTest.getBMW());
      doNothing.when(spy).setWheels(any());
      someClassTest.doSomething();
   }
}
```

It always sets the value to null, I I want it to be anything else but not null

Comment: `someClassTest` doesn't have your spy. It has the original object. Your spy only exists inside `doSomethingTest`.

Comment: I don't see here where your spy object would get injected; you're using a `createBMW()` in the setup for the car test, so the spy you create in `doSomethingTest()` won't get used

Comment: but even if I make something like ```@Spy private Car carTest``` I can spy only the car as a whole, cant spy objects inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
BMW spy = spy(carTest.getBMW());
```

You are creating a new `spy` instance that acts as proxy to real object. The spy is supposed to capture some of the calls, and proxy another calls to underlying "real" object that it spies on.

In order to get it work, you would have to pass your `spy` into live object in `setup` so every calls to your bmw will be made trought spy eg

```
carTest = new Car(createVolkswagen(), spy(createBMW()));
```

than it will work.

Comment: thanks a lot, didn't know you can pass spy as a parameter, learned something new again.

Comment: Without is, you cannot use your spy at all.